# Drupal 7 CTools Upgrade Gives Ajax Popup Error

Tags: drupal, drupal-ctools

We upgraded our core modules just fine.  We then upgraded Ctools and Date module and our popups are now throwing errors.  jQuery versions look the same.  I've searched and cannot find why this is happening.  Error is below:

We upgraded our modules. Now, our pop-up login gives us this error:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
>   HTTP Result Code: 404
>   Debugging information follows.
>   Path: /pop/ajax/login
>   StatusText: Not Found
>   ResponseText:
>   Page not found | TeachHUB
>   var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

I checked out some threads and enabled Custom Content Panes and it still does not work. The Firebug error is this:

> pop/ajax/login 404 Not Found

However, the link that the button goes to is pop/nojs/login.

http://drupal.org/node/1335664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using drupal 7 then you can use drupal 7's inbuilt overly module to open pop up that is very easy then CTOOLs